# How to edit a question even when someone has an suggested edit?

Tags: support, questions, suggested-edits, editing-help

So you will have "edit" under your post.

When you see "edit(1)", you click on it and it makes you approve or reject the edit suggestion, so how to do a personal edit then?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you have full edit privileges (gained at 2k rep) or it's your own post:

- If you don't like the suggested edit, simply choose "Reject and Edit", which will allow you to edit the post without applying the suggested edit.
- If you like the suggested edit, choose "Improve edit", which will allow you to make changes to the post with the suggested changes applied.

It's as simple as that and doesn't require messing with the URL. If you do mess with the URL to edit it outside of the suggested edit window, you will end up rejecting the edit anyway while applying (or having to revert) the suggested edit's changes. It's a bad option so don't do it!

Comment: Correct better then mine, but still you need to have two users do the same thing, no?

Comment: @U9-Forward No, that only happens when you hit "approve" or "reject". Edits you do yourself are always immediately applied to posts, even when there's already a suggested edit. So you might be the only reviewer.